# Repeatedly rolling a die and the tails of the multinomial distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, distribution-tails

For $1\leq i\leq n$ let $X_i$ be independent random variables, and let each $X_i$ be the uniform distribution on the set ${0,1,2,\dots,m}$ so that $X_i$ is like an $m+1$ sided die.  Let $$Y=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{m} X_i,$$ so that $\mathbb{E}(Y)=\frac{1}{2}$.  I am interested in the tails of this distribution, that is the size of $$\Pr\left( Y \geq k\right)$$ where $\frac{1}{2}< k\leq 1$ is a constant.

In the case where $m=1$, we are looking at the binomial distribution, and $$\Pr\left( Y \geq k\right)= \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^{(1-k) n} \binom{n}{i}$$ and we can bound this above by $(1-k)n \binom{n}{(1-k)n}$ and below by $\binom{n}{(1-k)n}$ which yields $$\Pr\left( Y \geq k\right)\approx \frac{1}{2^n} e^{n H(k)}$$ where $H(x)=-\left(x\log x+(1-x)\log (1-x)\right)$ is the entropy function.  (I use approx liberally)

What kind of similar bounds do we have on the tails of this distribution when  $m\geq 2$?  I am looking to use the explicit multinomial properties to get something stronger than what you would get using Chernoff of Hoeffding.

Comment: Something is missing in your m=1 formula. The right hand side is an integer >1.  The formula has to involve the parameter p=P(Xi=1)

Comment: @MichaelChernick: I have edited.  There should of been a factor of $2^{-n}$ in front.  Since $p=1-p$, get exactly $2^{-n}$ in each factor.

Comment: I think that maybe a Tex symbol is causing the 1/2$^n$ term to not appear in your edited question. Never mind.  I see it is there now.

Comment: Chernoff yields the exact rate of the exponential convergence to zero. What do you call *stronger* than that?

Comment: @Did:  Could you elaborate on what you mean by this?  This could be exactly what I am looking for.  (Also, I may not be using the correct version of Chernoff's inequality)

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: @did: Thanks, that answers things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider some i.i.d. random variables $\xi$ and $(\xi_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ with mean $\mathrm E(\xi)=0$ and finite exponential moment $\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t|\xi|})$ for every $t$. Then, for every $x\gt0$, there exists  $I(x)\gt0$ such that, when $n\to\infty$,
$$
\mathrm P(\xi_1+\cdots+\xi_n\geqslant nx)=\mathrm e^{-nI(x)+o(n)}.
$$
Furthermore, optimizing Chernoff exponential upper bound yields the exact value of the exponent $I(x)$. Namely, recall that, for every nonnegative $t$,
$$
\mathrm P(\xi_1+\cdots+\xi_n\geqslant nx)\leqslant\left(\mathrm e^{-tx}\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t\xi})\right)^n=\mathrm e^{-nI(t,x)},
$$
where
$$
I(t,x)=tx-\log\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t\xi}),
$$
and it happens that
$$
I(x)=\sup\limits_{t\geqslant0}I(t,x).
$$
Note that $\mathrm E(\xi)=0$ hence $\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t\xi})=1+o(t)$ when $t\to0$ and $I(t,x)=tx+o(t)$. In particular, $I(t,x)\gt0$ for $t\gt0$ small enough, hence $I(x)\gt0$ and the upper bound above is not trivial.

As stated above, this upper bound also provides the exact behaviour, in the exponential scale, of the probability of the *large deviations event* considered, that is,
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\log\mathrm P(\xi_1+\cdots+\xi_n\geqslant nx)=-I(x).
$$
In your setting, one considers $\xi=\frac1mX-\frac12$ and $x=k-\frac12$ hence $0\lt x\lt\frac12$. Note finally that, in general, $I(x)=I(t_x,x)$ where $t_x$ solves the equation $\partial_tI(t,x)=0$, that is,
$$
x\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t\xi})=\mathrm E(\xi\mathrm e^{t\xi}).
$$

Comment: How can I evaluate $I(x)$ explicitly in my case?

Comment: You know the distribution of $\xi=\frac1mX-\frac12$ with $X$ uniform on $\{0,1,\ldots,m\}$ hence you know $\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t\xi})$ and $\mathrm E(\mathrm e^{t\xi})$ and $I(t,x)$ hence you know $I(x)$.

Comment: In what I did above in the question with binomial coefficients, when $m=1$, I found that $I(x)=\log 2 - H(x)$ where $H$ is the entropy function.  How can I evaluate the expectations above and find $I(x)$ when $m$ is different?  I conjecture that it is like $\log(m+1) -H(x)$ with the same entropy function $H$, but I am not sure.

Comment: There is no reason to believe $I(x)$ has this form when $m\geqslant2$ and in fact, tedious computations show that it has not when $m=2$.

Comment: Eric: Thanks for the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

The variance of $X_i$ is $\frac{m(m+2)}{12}$ so of $Y$ is $\frac{m+2}{12mn}$. The central limit theorem leads to a normal approximation for moderate to high $n$

$$\Pr\left( Y \geq k\right) \approx 1 - \Phi\left((2k-1){\sqrt{\frac{3mn}{m+2}}}\right)$$

[Stein's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_method) and other similar methods can help calculate the rates of convergence